# set parameters in http get request in qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, http-get

I have a line of code Where i want to set parameters which has a boolean value in aRequest. How do  set it in qt c++?

```
else if(requestPath.startsWith("/internal/Services")){    // note URL is /internal/...
     windowsservice().service(aRequest, aResponse)
 }
```

Comment: What is `aRequest`? What does `service()` do? Does it send POST or GET request?

Comment: Well, I meant is it QNetworkRequest or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some assumptions about your code, try something like this:

```
auto url = aRequest.url();
QUrlQuery query{url};
query.addQueryItem("boolparam", "1");
url.setQuery(query);
aRequest.setUrl(url);
```